# How auto-reset permissions works in Android 11 with device admin?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-11, device-admin

I have an application that is a device administrator. First, a little disclaimer, our app has an MDM intention (Mobile Device Management), so it is not supposed to be used by end-users.

Since our app is mostly used as a background device manager, I'm testing the new flag that allows your app to not have all permissions reset. I noticed a strange behavior when the device admin is on, and I can't find any documentation about it in Android 11 changes, nor in sdk reference documentation. When your app is device admin, you can't toggle this flag anymore since it's disabled.

If, when I first open my app, asks for device administration and then test the result of `context.packageManager.isAutoRevokeWhitelisted` ([ref](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#isAutoRevokeWhitelisted())) it returns *false*. But the toggle button in the app settings is disabled, so I can't turn it on.

If I, before asking my app to be device admin, go to app settings and toggle the flag to whitelist our app, then after admin is granted, the toggle is disabled, and this method returns *true*, which is what I'm looking for.

So my question is: if I turn on device admin for my app, does this means that it will automatically be whitelisted, so I don't need to worry about this (what would explain the toggle disabled, but not explain why the method returns *false*) or I should first ask for the app to be whitelisted (changing the toggle button in settings) and then ask for device admin?